# Wordpress showing thumbnail does not work

Tags: wordpress, themes, thumbnails

I am making an wordpress website where I am going to upload some pictures and videos. Just for a test, I wrote some posts and uploaded a picture.

I am using https://tzm.wordpress.org/themes/rowling/ theme

At the front page, there should be some recent posts with thumbnails.

But, in my wordpress, thumbnail does not work while recent posts are working.

I checked some php files like functions.php or content.php to see if they have some thumbnail functions.

At the content.php, I found some thumbnail codes

```
<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('post'); ?>>

<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>

    <div class="post-image">

        <?php if ( is_sticky() ) : ?>
            <a class="sticky-tag" title="<?php _e('Sticky post:','rowling'); echo ' '; the_title_attribute(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <span class="fa fw fa-star"></span>
            </a>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <a title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">    

            <?php the_post_thumbnail('post-image-thumb'); ?>

        </a>

    </div> <!-- /post-image -->
```

but why my wordpress does not show thumbnails? Should I add something more?

Answer (score 0):

You might be putting images in the content area of the post.

If the theme is supporting the featured image, there should be a section called featured image on the right bottom side of your post dashboard. Choose some images from there and update your post.